# How do I perform rotations about an object's local (not global) axes using glRotatef?

Tags: c++, opengl, freeglut

I have a mesh/game object to rotate with glRotatef, using the FreeGLUT library:

```
glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(GlobalPos_x, GlobalPos_y, GlobalPos_z);

    glRotatef(Global_Yaw,0,1,0);
    glRotatef(Global_Pitch,1,0,0);
    glRotatef(Global_Roll,0,0,1);

    RenderMesh(mesh_Plane);
glPopMatrix();
```

At start, the object is aligned with the forward Z-axis;
The Y-axis goes up, and the X-axis goes left.

---

'Controls':

W: Pitch +5 deg per frame

S: Pitch -5 deg per frame

A: Yaw +5 deg per frame

D: Yaw -5 deg per frame

---

**GOAL: The Global_Yaw, Global_Pitch and Global_Roll values must somehow increment from these controls (ranges of -180 to +180, -90 to +90 and -180 to +180 respectively).**

Problem is, if the plane is already pitched up 90 degrees from
its original positon, 'yawing' would instead make it spin around
the Y-axis (gimbal lock), which should only happen in a First-
Person Shooter.

So simply doing 'if(GetAsyncKeyState(Key_A)) Global_Yaw += 5;' is not what I'm looking for.

---

## Edit: Square 2

Following tkausl's reminder, I dug up one of my earlier attempts. My idea was that I'd convert the Airplane's current Global Angles into a matrix, multiply that matrix with another matrix generated by the player's key inputs, then somehow using this matrix to get new Global_Yaw, Global_Pitch and Global_Roll values:

```
// Convert ORIENTATION to MATRIX
Omatrix00 = cos(Global_Pitch)*cos(Global_Yaw);
Omatrix01 = sin(Global_Pitch);
Omatrix02 = cos(Global_Pitch)*sin(Global_Yaw);
Omatrix03 = 0;
Omatrix10 = -cos(Global_Roll)*sin(Global_Pitch)*cos(Global_Yaw)+sin(Global_Roll)*sin(Global_Yaw);
Omatrix11 = cos(Global_Roll)*cos(Global_Pitch);
Omatrix12 = -cos(Global_Roll)*sin(Global_Pitch)*sin(Global_Yaw)-sin(Global_Roll)*cos(Global_Yaw);
Omatrix13 = 0;
Omatrix20 = -sin(Global_Roll)*sin(Global_Pitch)*cos(Global_Yaw)-cos(Global_Roll)*sin(Global_Yaw);
Omatrix21 = sin(Global_Roll)*cos(Global_Pitch);
Omatrix22 = cos(Global_Roll)*cos(Global_Yaw)-sin(Global_Roll)*sin(Global_Pitch)*sin(Global_Yaw);
Omatrix23 = 0;
Omatrix30 = 0;
Omatrix31 = 0;
Omatrix32 = 0;
Omatrix33 = 1;


// Convert Commanded Turn Angles to MATRIX
matrix00 = cos(pitch_speed)*cos(yaw_speed);
matrix02 = cos(pitch_speed)*sin(yaw_speed);
matrix01 = sin(pitch_speed);
matrix03 = 0;
matrix10 = -cos(roll_speed)*sin(pitch_speed)*cos(yaw_speed)+sin(roll_speed)*sin(yaw_speed);
matrix11 = cos(roll_speed)*cos(pitch_speed);
matrix12 = -cos(roll_speed)*sin(pitch_speed)*sin(yaw_speed)-sin(roll_speed)*cos(yaw_speed);
matrix13 = 0;
matrix20 = -sin(roll_speed)*sin(pitch_speed)*cos(yaw_speed)-cos(roll_speed)*sin(yaw_speed);
matrix21 = sin(roll_speed)*cos(pitch_speed);
matrix22 = cos(roll_speed)*cos(yaw_speed)-sin(roll_speed)*sin(pitch_speed)*sin(yaw_speed);
matrix23 = 0;
matrix30 = 0;
matrix31 = 0;
matrix32 = 0;
matrix33 = 1;

// Next step: Somehow using this matrix to get new Global_Yaw, Global_Pitch and Global_Roll values...
```

I'm not even sure I was multiplying my matrices correctly in my code either.

Answer (score 0):

You have to rotate around the x- or z-axis first and y last to get the correct outcome. In the most type of games you don't need roll, you'd rotate around x, then around z, and everything is rotating as expected.

Comment: That doesn't quite help me... My question was, the Global_Yaw, Global_Pitch and Global_Roll values must somehow increment from the WASD controls. (From -180 to +180, -90 to +90 and -180 to +180 respectively). Nevertheless, I'll edit my question to better reflect my problem.

Comment: Oh i think i get it. In this case, you have to use quaternions and matrices to prevent the gimbal lock